# I'm getting an internal server 500 error and I don't know how to debug it

Tags: java, backend, http-status-code-500, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to upload a file to a springboot server and the upload feature is throwing this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8923)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3894)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: jakarta.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:960)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:794)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$2(JerseyInvocation.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:686)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:357)
    at client.utils.ServerUtils.internalPostRequest(ServerUtils.java:77)
    at client.utils.ServerUtils.saveFile(ServerUtils.java:266)
    at client.scenes.MediaPlayerCtrl.save(MediaPlayerCtrl.java:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: jakarta.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
```

From what I'm getting the error happens in ServerUtils.internalPostRequest(ServerUtils.java:77) and ServerUtils.saveFile(ServerUtils.java:266) as the MediaPlayerCtrl.save(MediaPlayerCtrl.java:117) is simply calling the saveFile() method. I think this leads back to the FileController on the server, but I have no idea what might be causing the error. I'll leave the methods I referenced earlier down below.

```
private <T> T internalPostRequest(String path, Entity send, GenericType<T> retType) {
        return ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig())
                .target(getServer()).path(path)
                .request(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(send, retType);
    }

public void saveFile(File file){
        internalPostRequest("secure/" + store.accessStore().getUsername() + "/file/add",
                Entity.entity(file, APPLICATION_JSON), new GenericType<>(){});
    }
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/secure/{username}/{password}/file", "/secure/{username}/file"})
public class FileController {
    @Autowired
    private StorageService service;
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException     {
        String uploadFile = service.uploadFile(file);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(uploadFile);
    }
```

```
@Service
public class StorageService {
    @Autowired
    private StorageRepository repository;

    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        FileData fileData = repository.save(new FileData(file.getOriginalFilename(),
                        file.getContentType(), compressFile(file.getBytes())));
        return "File uploaded succesfully: "+ file.getOriginalFilename();
    }

    public static byte[] compressFile(byte[] data) {
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
        deflater.setInput(data);
        deflater.finish();

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
        while (!deflater.finished()) {
            int size = deflater.deflate(tmp);
            outputStream.write(tmp, 0, size);
        }
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public String getType(String fileName){
        Optional<FileData> dbFileData = repository.findByName(fileName);
        if (dbFileData.isPresent()) {
            return dbFileData.get().getType();
        } else {
            return "File not found: " + fileName;
        }
    }
```

I tried going down the rabbit hole as deep as I could, but I didn't really notice anything going wrong. For context: this is supposed to handle media files - photo (jpg, png) and video(mp3, mp4, wav etc.)

Comment: I will assume that your client is a javafx app. Did you try without fx? I mean with curl or postman. If it is a simple file upload from some client (angular, react, javafx, android, etc) should be easy. Also **{username}/{password}** is a bad idea!

Comment: Just a fast view but servers don't ........,. javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)

Comment: You posted the client exception, but there should be one on the server as well - which is where the problem actually occurred (the `StorageService` class) - so that is the more relevant one.